# How to import excel file which is non defined way to sql server

Tags: sql-server, excel

I'm new in c# and i feel i m in trouble.
in my project i want to import excel file to sql server 2008 but i want to user choose the excel file.i search lots of source but *all of them define the way of excel file in the code*,but i want to user browse and user select excel file.Then other things row -row or colomn will transfer to sql server.
On the other hand i would give information on my project,it will be good for me to explain problem.First user selects excel file and it will be imported database again user selects other excel file one by one.The importent thing is how i can give way of excel file dynamically. 
 if you will help,i will be grateful.
**Thank you...**

Comment: Well in that case, you would need to program something like the [SQL Server Data Import Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx) - definitely a non-trivial task in terms of complexity and time ...

Comment: So you want the user to select an Excel file in a dialog window, and the whole file will be uploaded and saved in SQL server, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

hi it looks like you need to use Open File Dialog box. Here is the example code how to use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773.aspx
However, remember that if you are going to deploy this application to any server you have to bear in mind that you cant use traditional ways of initiating Excel objects and reading the data in sheets. As you will not have MS office installed on server. And if you install them you will be violating the licence. Here is an example how you can do the actual import
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/115578/Excel-to-SQL-without-JET-or-OLE-Version-2

Comment: i look up the article but i want to  the user to select an Excel file in a dialog window, and the whole file will be uploaded and saved in SQL server.Thank you.

Comment: the article i pointed gives you what to use but here you go http://www.dotnetperls.com/openfiledialog this one will tell you what to do. Now when you say you want whole file to be uploaded what do you mean? are your columns always fixed ?

Comment: are you using windows forms or ASP.net?

Comment: i m using windows forms.And i will upload whole file and i use all columns in the file.

Comment: i think then the articles which i have provided will help you to achieve what you are trying.